# Summation with Complex Numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, summation

What is the general form of a summation with complex numbers?
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i$$ For real numbers/natural numbers this can be done, but an this be done for complex numbers such that i is a complex number and goes to a complex number OR infinity.

Note that I am **not** talking about something like:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{5} 5n(i) + \frac{n}{5}$$
I mean strictly where n/i is a complex number.

Comment: Do you mean you want to choose the index set as a subset of complex numbers?

Comment: How would you define the order that the summation should follow? Any way, if $S \subseteq \mathbb C$ is your favorite collection of complex numbers, then the sum can be written as $$\sum_{z \in S} f(z).$$

Comment: @KenHung correct index $\subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Azif00How would the order work though that was my main question

Comment: "For real numbers/natural numbers this can be done, "  How do you think it is done for real numbers?  In $\sum_{k=1}^n a_i$ then index $k$ is a natural number and you go through them one by one.  The  $a_i$ individually can be anything and are not restricted to reals, but the *index* in this summation is limited to *naturals*.

Comment: @Azif00  If $S = \{z: |z| > 1\}$ then what is $\sum\limits_{z \in S} z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^n a_i$ is shorthand for there being a function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ where $f(i) = a_i$ and we are summing $\sum\limits_{i\in \mathbb N} f(i)$ which is a general case of $S$ being a finite or countable set and we sum $\sum\limits_{s\in S} s$ (this assumes the countable sum converges and this would not be meaningful on any set where the sum doesn't) and we can rewrite $\sum_{k=1}^n a_i=\sum\limits_{i\in \mathbb N} f(i)$ as $\sum\limits_{a\in f(\mathbb N)} a$ if we wanted to.

Now it doesn't matter in the least the $s\in S$ are real or complex  or any other space where addition is defined.  That's not and never was the issue.  Your concern is *entirely* about how we *index* the elements.  And you were quite mistaken when you said we index them with uncountably many real numbers.  We can't do any such thing  $\sum\limits_{r\in \mathbb R} a_r$ simply doesn't make any sense because adding uncountably many $a_r$ is ill-defined.

Unless.... you are define $a + b$ to be something other than addition and we are defining it so that we *can* "add" uncountably many elements.  If instance we often, if $a$ and $b$ are sets define $a + b$ to be the union of $a+b$ so if we have a set $a_z$ associated with every $z\in \mathbb C$ we can say $\sum\limits_{z\in \mathbb C} a_z = \cup_{z\in \mathbb Z} a_z$.  Nothing odd or peculiar about that.

====

From comment:

> You are correct that my main concern is how is the complex iterator defined.

An iterator is a constant value iterated a *natural* number of times.

So if you you want to add $f(1+2i) + f(2+4i) + f(3+6i)$ as $\sum f(k)$ we'd just index $\sum\limits_{w=1+2i; (1+2i)+}^{|w|\le M}a_w$ and hope it is clear in context that that means $\sum\limits_{w\in\{z=n(1+2i)|n\in \mathbb N, |z|\le M\}}a_w$

....

but my main point is that the notation for summation is $\text{the sum of all items with a certain condition} := \sum\limits_{s \text{ such that }s\text{ has a certain property}} s$.

It's just that the "certain condition" so *often* is "$s$ is a member of a finite or countable set" and a countable set can have its elements enumerated it makes sense to devise a notation $\sum\limits_{s\in\{a_1,a_2,....\}} s= \sum\limits_{a_i\in\{a_1,a_2,....\}}a_i$ as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\text{some upper bound}}a_i$.

Furthermore it is so common to have the elements $a_i$  be directly determined from $i$ via an "iterator" so it makes sense to notate $\sum\limits_{k=firstterm;iterator}^{terminator}a_k$.  this assumes we iterate over a natural number times. what type of object the iterator is doesn't matter so long as it can be iterated over.

Comment: I wasn't saying that we index them with uncountably many real numbers I was just saying that the iterator "distance" is defined from Reals to Reals, or Real to Infinity. You are correct that my main concern is how is the complex iterator defined. I don't really follow your last paragraph, how do we iterate from $\sum_{z_1}^{z_2}  a_z$

Comment: Going to Clarify here, that I know that $$z \in \mathbb_{C}$$
*(not sure why that LaTeX isn't working)

 but how would that iterator actually work for a summation, such that the summation yields any number assuming the summation does not diverge. Basically, how do you from the bottom part of the summation to the top part. Since a Complex Number has a real and complex part it is much more tricky that a standard summation with just one part to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful